# Vertically STACK bootstrap input-group controls

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

So the normal behavior of the input-group controls of bootstrap is horizontal stacking within the 100% of the container. What I'd like to do is stack them on top of each other so instead of having this:
[image: horizontal bootstrap input-group]

I'll have this:

[image: vertical bootstrap input-group]

(If you wonder, the vertical image is done by paint :))

So far I have tried

```
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">One</span>
    <select class="form-control"><option>1</option></select>
</div>
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">One</span>
    <select class="form-control"><option>1</option></select>
</div>
```

[image: first failed try]

And this (which I don't think is supported by bootstrap)

```
<div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">One</span>
        <select class="form-control"><option>1</option></select>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">One</span>
        <select class="form-control"><option>1</option></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: second failed try]

As you can see, it's stacked as I want it to be - only that it is very small (not spanned over 100% of the container) AND the joined part has border-radius.

Must I tamper with/override the css styles of the input-group to achieve my goal is there any other preferred/supported way?

Comment: Have a look at the class="form-horizontal" if it's in your mark up. I think you can either omit it or change it to form vertical. Regarding the spacing, you might have to do the css stuff for margins, paddings and borders.

Comment: Doesn't exist in my markup

Comment: Just realized that it wouldn't give you what you're after, since it would only affect the way the labels and data are stacked. Sorry. And, there isn't a form-vertical.

Comment: @nocturns2 Decided to wrap it with a custom class. Looks pretty nice though! Solution is in the post if you are interested.

Comment: @SharonJDDorot You should post your solution as an answer instead of updating the question with the answer. It's perfectly acceptable and encouraged to answer your own questions.

Answer (score 7):

I just used this with Bootstrap 4. I added an additional CSS rule in order to remove the thick border between input fields.

```css
.vertical-input-group .input-group:first-child {
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
.vertical-input-group .input-group:first-child * {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;    
}
.vertical-input-group .input-group:last-child {
    padding-top: 0;
}
.vertical-input-group .input-group:last-child * {
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
}
.vertical-input-group .input-group:not(:last-child):not(:first-child) {
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
.vertical-input-group .input-group:not(:last-child):not(:first-child) * {
    border-radius: 0;
}  
.vertical-input-group .input-group:not(:first-child) * {
    border-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="vertical-input-group">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sao" placeholder="Attention Of">
    </div>

    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ad1" placeholder="Line 1">
    </div>
    
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ad2" placeholder="Line 2">
    </div>

    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ad3" placeholder="Line 3">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ad4" placeholder="Line 4">
    </div>

    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ad5" placeholder="City">
    </div>

    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="county" placeholder="County">
    </div>

    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="postalcode" placeholder="Postal Code">
    </div>

</div>
```

[Vertical Aligned with thin border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdGmp.png)